# Why does the GridView disappear after a button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upExec" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <button type="button" runat="server" id="btnExec" onserverclick="btnExec_Click" class="btnAll btnExec">Execute SQL Job</button>
        <asp:Label ID="lblEMsg" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Text=""></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upGV" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView EmptyDataText="No Provider Exists" ID="gvData" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-Width="5%" DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-Width="5%" DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    ViewState["sortOrder"] = "Asc";
    ViewState["sortExp"] = "Due Date";
    ShowGridView("Name", "Asc");
}

public void ShowGridView(string sortExp, string sortDir)
{
    using (SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection(gloString))
    {
        try
        {
            sc.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(strQuery, sc);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            sda.Fill(ds);

            DataView dv = new DataView();
            dv = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;

            gvData.DataSource = dv;
            gvData.DataBind();
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            sc.Close();
        }
    }
    upGV.Update();
}

public void btnExec_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection(gloString))
    {
        try
        {
            sc.Open();
            using (SqlCommand scd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                scd.CommandText = "MySP";
                scd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                scd.Connection = sc;

                scd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            sc.Close();
        }
    }

    using (SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection(floString))
    {
        try
        {
            sc.Open();
            SqlCommand scd = new SqlCommand();
            scd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            scd.Connection = sc;
            scd.CommandText = "msdb.dbo.sp_start_job";
            scd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@job_name", "JobName");

            using (scd)
            {
                scd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                ShowGridView("Name", "Asc");
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            sc.Close();
        }
    }

    upExec.Update();
}
```

When the page first loads, I can see the GridView. When I click the `btnExec`, the GridView disappears and it displays "No Provider Exists". When I check the source of the page the data is still there.

How can I resolve it so when the button is clicked, it performs the stored procedure and reloads the GridView with the new data.

Comment: Are you still have the issue?

Comment: Yes i do for some reason cant seem to figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you should move the call to ShowGridView() in your btnExec_Click() method to outside the outer "using" statement, right before the call to upExec.Update().

Comment: It is still the same thing :/ I don't know why it keeps saying No Provider Exists. If I debug it works fine but without debugging it doesn't. Any idea?

Comment: I removed the `if (!Page.IsPostBack)` section and let the GridView always populate on page load and it works fine. Weird, so the function call within the Click method isn't working for some reason. :/

Comment: Have you tried debugging and setting break points in visual studio to see if the btn_click is being called? Also, what line is causing the message "No Provider Exists" ??

Comment: When I debug it works fine but when I just hit the Continue button to execute without debugging I get the error.

Comment: I figured out why it was doing that because I am running a job which copies the data to a temp table and then exports it to another table and hence the data wasn't exported to the new table. I can either have a delay before updating the GridView or have another button that updates the GridView.

Comment: I see. Well is there anyway you can use a stored procedure instead of a job to copy the data to the temp table and export it? Because a stored procedure will return when the whole thing is complete and then you can be sure that the table is ready when you choose to bind it to the data grid.

Comment: Your method works somewhat so I +1 and accepted it. I won't post my solution because technically all the code is correct except I needed to delay the populating of the GridView by 15 seconds. On a side note, I think I am running a SP to copy over the data.

Answer (score 0):

On my case, I had to add this attribute to the panel that was wrapping my GridView to keep it visible and working, every time I was clicking on a row to select it, it kept disappearing :

`<asp:Panel EnableViewState="True">`